# R PostgreSQL - data is not getting updated in the table of the database

Tags: r, postgresql, rpostgresql

Hi I am trying to update a postgresql table using RpostgreSQL package, the commands in R are executed successfully but the new data is not getting reflected in the database. Below are the commands i have executed in R

```
for(i in new_data$FIPS) {
  drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
  con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname="ip_platform", host="******", port="5432", user="data_loader", password="******")
  txt <- paste("UPDATE adminvectors.county SET attributes= hstore('usco@TP-TotPop@2010'::TEXT,",new_data$TP.TotPop[new_data$FIPS == i],"::TEXT) where geoid ='",i,"'")
  dbGetQuery(con, txt)
  dbCommit(con)
  dbDisconnect(con)
}
```

Can anyone let me know if I have done something wrong? Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Not sure if it will change anything but you probably want to use `dbSendQuery` instead of `dbGetQuery` because you aren't actually pulling anything.  Also, you need to commit before disconnecting.

Comment: Well i have tried dbSendQuery as well but still having the same problem. For each iteration the dbCommit is returning a warning saying "There is no transaction in progress"

Comment: @sckott  Major groan.  What exactly is your issue with RPostgreSQL which actually *has been on CRAN* since 2008?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling dbGetQuery instead of dbSendQuery and also disconnecting from the database in your for loop. You also are creating a new connection object for every loop iteration, which is not necessary. Try this:

```
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname="ip_platform", host="******", port="5432", user="data_loader", password="******")

for(i in new_data$FIPS) {
  txt <- paste("UPDATE adminvectors.county SET attributes= hstore('usco@TP-TotPop@2010'::TEXT,",new_data$TP.TotPop[new_data$FIPS == i],"::TEXT) where geoid ='",i,"'")
  dbSendQuery(con, txt)
}

dbDisconnect(con)
```

You shouldn't call `dbCommit(con)` explicitly. The enclosing transaction will always be commited when dbSendQuery returns, exactly as when you do an `UPDATE` with pure SQL. You don't call `COMMIT` unless you have created a new transaction with `BEGIN TRANSACTION`.

The warning "there is no transaction in progress" is PostgreSQL's way of telling you that you have issued a `COMMIT` statement without having issued a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` statement which is exactly what you are doing in your function.

Comment: The maximum number of connections were exceeding when i disconnect the connection after all the iterations, that is the reason i was trying to establish and disconnect the connection for each iteration of the for loop

Answer (score 0):

Simplify, simplify, simplify -- the RPostgreSQL has had unit tests for these types of operations since the very beginning (in 2008 no less) and this works (unless you have database setup issues).

See eg [here in the GitHub repo](https://github.com/tomoakin/RPostgreSQL/tree/master/RPostgreSQL/tests) for all the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your inputs. 
The issue is with the paste() function which I used in the for loop. The paste() function has replaced the comma with a space in the query as a result the where condition is failing. I have added a sep="" attribute in the paste() and the query is now properly sent to the database and the rows are getting updated as expected.